# Xcode Swift, will console logs affect App Store approval? App works fine regardless

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I am about to release the 2nd version of my app, however, I seem to face console logs that seem a bit frustrating. My app works completely fine even with the issues, but these console logs are delaying my App Store submission. Will Apple take into review the console logs or not? Thanks for any help

Comment: No. It will not reivew you console log.

Comment: @vishnu anilkumar oh ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

The console log is not matter in your app review from apple. You can simply remove the unnecessary logs from console with add environmental variable from edit scheme like below:
[image]

I hope it will help you regarding your problem or issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Yes I have set that to disable thanks for the information